# Swift firestore delete document

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, document

I would like to delete a document from my firestore DB. But my code only makes me delete all documents. Somehow i need to get DocumentID corresponding to the line in the tableview I'm swiping. Any suggestions?

My code looks like this;

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        self.db.collection("Miljoskjema").getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in

            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in snapshot!.documents {

                    document.reference.delete()

                    }
                }}}
```

Comment: Do you know the document id?

Comment: The snapshot gets all the document id’s. But i dont know how to refer the selected row in the tableview to the fight document ID

Answer (score 0):

When you load the documents from Firestore, you'll need to maintain a list of the document IDs to match up with the list of values that you show in the table view. Then you can look up the document ID when the user swipes a value, and delete the document with:

```
self.db.collection("Miljoskjema").doc(documentId).delete()
```

If you're looking for inspiration on how to do that, have a look at the [FirebaseUI implementation of its data sources](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/tree/master/Firestore/FirebaseFirestoreUI). The `FUIBatchedArray` in there keeps the [documents](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/Firestore/FirebaseFirestoreUI/FUIBatchedArray.m#L78) it gets from Firestore, which you can then [get by their index](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/Firestore/FirebaseFirestoreUI/FUIBatchedArray.m#L108), which the `TableViewDataSource` then uses to [implement `cellForRowAtIndexPath`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/Firestore/FirebaseFirestoreUI/FUIFirestoreTableViewDataSource.m#L162).